# jQuery cloned list items all get the same text values while using each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, each, zepto

I am trying to clone a list item in the DOM and append it multiple times depending on the number of text values in the variable *data* using the each function. The problem is that all the new list items get the same text values (all list items are set equal to the last appended list item). 
I suppose it has something to do with enclosures, but I cannot figure it out.

Can anyone explain what the problem is?

Thanks!

**data:**

```
    var data = {"text1": ["text1_row1", "text1_row2"], "text2": ["text2_row1", "text2_row2"], "text3": ["text3_row1", "text3_row2"] }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <ul>
        <li id="entryTemplate" style="display:none">
            <span class="text1"></span>
            <span class="text2"></span>
            <span class="text3"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function listData(data){
    $.each(data.text1, function(i) {
        var newDataRow = $('#entryTemplate').clone();   
        newDataRow.removeAttr('id')
             .removeAttr('style')
             .removeAttr('class')
             .addClass('copy')
             .appendTo('ul')
             .find('.text1').text(data.text1[i])
             .find('.text2').text(data.text2[i])
             .find('.text3').text(data.text3[i]);
    });
}

$.fn.clone = function(){
    var ret = $();
    this.each(function(){
        ret.push(this.cloneNode(true))
    });
    return ret;
};
```

**Desired HTML:**

```
    <ul>
        <li id="entryTemplate" style="display:none">
            <span class="text1"></span>
            <span class="text2"></span>
            <span class="text3"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="copy">
            <span class="text1">text1_row1</span>
            <span class="text2">text2_row1</span>
            <span class="text3">text3_row1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="copy">
            <span class="text1">text1_row2</span>
            <span class="text2">text2_row2</span>
            <span class="text3">text3_row2</span>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

**Result I get (all li items get the text for row2):**

```
    <ul>
        <li id="entryTemplate" style="display:none">
            <span class="text1"></span>
            <span class="text2"></span>
            <span class="text3"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="copy">
            <span class="text1">text1_row2</span>
            <span class="text2">text2_row2</span>
            <span class="text3">text3_row2</span>
        </li>
        <li class="copy">
            <span class="text1">text1_row2</span>
            <span class="text2">text2_row2</span>
            <span class="text3">text3_row2</span>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit foggy and it's not really clear what's the result you're looking for. Appart from that I saw something in your code that's probably causing it. Give it a try and let me know what happened.

When you do

```
$.each(data.text1, function(i) {
```

change it to

```
$.each(data.text1, function(pos, element) {
```

and replace your [ i ] for [element].

According to JQuery API, when doing an EACH loop, the 1st return is the position in the array and the second is the value itself.

Comment: I updated the question to try to make it less foggy. I want to use the position of the array since I need to use it to get other text elements from my json array.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER:

Your data object variable is formatted wrong... It looks like you want each value of the data object to be an array (using curly brackets implies you are defining an object with keys), so you should be using square brackets `[]`. See [array vs array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Examples)

```
var data = {
    "text1": ["text1_row1", "text1_row2"],
    "text2": ["text2_row1", "text2_row2"],
    "text3": ["text3_row1", "text3_row2"]
}
```

jQuery already has a [clone method](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) so you shouldn't need to override with your own.

Based on the data you provided, you want to be iterating over the `data` variable itself, not `data.text1`. Then you can get the text values by value of the current index (this is the second parameter passed to `.each()`) and referencing `[0]` and `[1]` to get the actual text

```
$.each(data,function(i,value){
  console.log(value);
  var newDataRow = $("#entryTemplate").clone();
  newDataRow
  .removeAttr('id')
  .removeAttr('style')
  .removeAttr('class')
  .addClass('copy')
  .appendTo('ul');
  newDataRow.children('.text1').text(value[0]); // value[0] == data[i][0]
  newDataRow.children('.text2').text(value[1]);
});
```

Comment: I tried to use the add function but still couldn't get it to work. I updated my question to make it clear what my goal and problems are...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... my data object variable is indeed formatted like that. Furthermore I realized that I use Zepto and when I remove my clone function it does not work anymore. I will try jQuery to see if that works..